# Triggering a stored procedure to run instead of INSERT (PL/SQL)

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

Given a simple employees table (id, lastname, firstname) the assignment requres me to write a stor proc that takes first and last names, figures out the next id and inserts a new record into the table. That's done. Next part's asking to write a trigger that will call this stor proc whenever a new INSERT happens. My understanding is that this trigger is supposed to intercept the insert statement that's triggered it, extract its arguments and run the stor proc INSTEAD (not before or after) of the insert. The problem is that instead-of triggers seem to only work with views which I'm not allowed to write. Any ideas on how this might be approached?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Basically, the INSERT should not even touch the table - all its work is required to be carried out by the stor proc. Is there a way to accomplish this via before/after trigger mechanisms?

Comment: I'd say it wasn't possible, see Tom Kyte's comment here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:686424821718#13851398091316.  If the assignment is genuinely asking you to write an instead-of trigger on a table, then it is a stupid assignment.

Comment: That's pretty much how I feel about it. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Actually it just requires me to use a trigger->stored proc approach. Does not specify what type of trigger to use. It just seems that BEFORE and AFTER triggers would not prevent insert from happening. Do you know if BEFORE trigger can "override" an insert statement?

Comment: If the purpose of the trigger is just to set a new ID, then you can use a BEFORE trigger to set the ID, and just let the insert happen.  In a BEFORE trigger you can assign to `:new.columnname` to change the value that gets inserted into a column.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle there are sequences. So you could create a sequence and then assign the next sequence number each time in the insert before trigger. Examples can be found here

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/sequences.html

and here

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/trigger/before_after_each_row.html

Let me know if you can do the assignment now or if you need more help.